# How to get session from signal handler in Django

Tags: django

I'm implementing a simple referral system. I have middleware which sets a session variable identifying the referring user. I have a model which ties a referring user to the referred user. I'm trying to use the post_save signal from the User object to populate this model. How do I access the session object from within the post_save signal handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way without using a [thread specific global variable](http://code.google.com/p/django-globals/).

But I'm not sure you need to.  For my referral and invite system I just have the user register as normal and after the user has been created, get the referral out of the session.  In almost all situations it will still be the same session.

If there is something about your session that prevents that, I would instead add it to the create user form.

Comment: I've got a few problems. 
1. My auth system is a separate app (built on django auth) which requires email activation. Users often don't log in for the firs time until after the session has expired. Thus, referral needs to be logged at creation.
2. I'm *trying* not to mess with auth (or creation) views/templates as I'm hoping to do this completely isolated from the auth system (if possible). Right now, it's not looking good.

Comment: Yeah, you are going to have to use global thread specific variables ... kind of awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful documentation [on using sessions out of views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views).

Comment: I was looking at that, but, I don't know how I would obtain the session key and I would have to know which type of session storage is being used.

Comment: AFAIK this does not work, since you don't have the session-key in the signal handler.